# Save single excel worksheet as new excel file with new input

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm working with vba and access 2010. I have here an excel file as a template, with 3 different worksheets and I would like to write stuff in these different worksheets depends on what is in my access db. I just have one trouble: the original excel template file should not be changed. I would like to save always in a new file with my input and this time only with 1 worksheet (depends whats in the access db).

So this is my code in access:

```
Dim excelObject As Object
Dim sheet As Object
Dim myRec As DAO.Recordset
Dim fldCustName As DAO.Field

'open excel file
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set excelObject = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("MyTemplate.xlsx")
Set sheet = excelObject.Worksheets(1)

'read table
Set myRec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyTable")
Set fldCustName = myRec.Fields("ID")

'select worksheet and add text to excel depends on table
If fldCustName = 1000 Then
    sheet.Cells(1, "A") = "Loop..."
End If
If fldCustName = 2000 Then
    sheet.Cells(1, "A") = "Loop..."
End If
'and so on...

'save and close
excelObject.Save 'problem: writes always in the same file and only worksheet 1
excelObject.Close
objExcel.Quit
```

As I said, the problem is that I save the changes always in my template.xlsx and I'm also ignoring the other worksheets. What is the easiest way to solve this? Maybe:

`reading the table -> decide which worksheet I need -> save this worksheet as .xlsx -> start writing`

But how? Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: replace `excelObject.Save` with `excelObject.SaveAs "new_file_path"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below saves your workbook in a new location with only one worksheet containing your output.

```
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts=False 'suppresses dialog boxes when deleting worksheets
Dim wsName As String

'replace this code with a function that gives you the name of the worksheet
wsName = "1"

'add your code to query the data and write to worksheet here

For Each Sh In excelObject.Worksheets
    If Sh.Name <> wsName Then
        Sh.Delete
    End If
Next Sh

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wsName & "output.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts=True
excelObject.Close
```

Comment: Hej thanks, that´s a good one. Just having some trouble with Sh.Delete - looks like that delete is only working if the sheet is empty. If there is already inside the sheet the code is not deleting this sheet.   Is there are workaround for that?

Comment: Hi silla, I just checked and I am actually able to delete worksheets with content using Sh.Delete. Could you explain what happens exactly when you try to delete a sheet with content? Do you receive an error message?

Comment: I don't see any error message, actually no messages at all. Tried with different excel files, but it´s always the same: sheets that I did not touch are deleted others with some input are not deleted. Thought 'Sh.Cells.Clear' could help (that would clear the sheet so I'm maybe able to delete), but this is not helping (sheet is now empty, but still not able to delete). Any idea how to debug or see what is going on behind the code?

Comment: Does the above help? What version of MS Office are you using?

Comment: Well I have to say that I'm not using the 'Application.DisplayAlerts = False' code of yours. I have no idea how to, because if I past it somewhere in my module I get a compile error message. Also 'FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled' is somehow not working for me, I get a "Runtime error 1004" so I'm saving the file without FileFormat. I'm using office 2010, my vba code is in access a module.

Comment: Since you are running the code from an access module, you might have to replace it by Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts=False ?

Comment: No thats also not working, but found out that there is actually no DisplayAlerts true/false in access. You just can use 'DoCmd.SetWarnings' False/True